# Google Analytics assign multiple values to a custom variable at pagelevel

Tags: google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics custom variable to track the category for a product. Product A has 3 categories: catA, catB and catC. This changes at page level because we load different products on different pages.

My code snippet looks like this:

```
_gaq.push('_setCustomVar', 1, 'categories', 'catA', 3);
_gaq.push('_trackPageview');
```

In order to set multiple categories, I need to send multiple `_trackPageView` or `_trackEvent` requests. Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We got around this by string concatenating our tags together with a `|` delimeter.  Some something like.

`_gaq.push('_setCustomVar', 1, 'categories', '|catA|catB|catC|', 3);
_gaq.push('_trackPageview');`

Then you can search for the tag in the UI

[image: search for catA in ui]

Not ideal, but better than tripling up on events/pageviews.

Comment: That's a decent workaround, but hard to scale when you have categories > 10. Have you explored options to widen dimensions? https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3191417?hl=en